# C# - UML - consulta y interpretacion

Tags: c#, uml

Queria saber si hize una correcta interpretacion del siguiente codigo  al graficar el UML.

```
class Sala
{
    protected arraylist butacas;
    private int capacidad;
    public sala(int c)
    {
        butacas = new arraylist();
        capacidad = c;
    }
}
class Cine : Sala
{
    private int numero;
    public Cine(int n, int c) : base(c)
    {
        numero = n;
    }
    public entraEspectador(Espectador e)
    {
        butacas.Add()e;
        e.sentateEn(butacas.count);
    }
}

class Espectador
    {
        private string nombre, apellido;
        private int butaca;
        public Espectador(string n, string a)
        {
            nombre = n;
            apellido = a;
        }
        public void sentate en(int b)
        {
            butaca = b;
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, hay varios errores. La mayoria es que estas creando variables donde son metodos.

Comment: Osea el marco se divide en 3 partes la primera de arriba es el nombre de la clase, la segunda son los atributos y la tercera son los metodos de la clase. Pero  la verdad una de las partes que no entiendo bien es la relacion entre "entra espectador" y "espectador"

Comment: Espectador es una clase y entraEspectador es un metodo que recibe un objeto de tipo Espectador.

Comment: entonces "entra espectador" iria en la tercera casilla de abajo? y ahi recien saco el rombo hacia espectador? y ahi estaria bien o sigue teniendo problemas?

Comment: Creo recordar que si ya tienes declarado como variable la colección de espectadores no hacia falta poner la agregación.

Comment: La clase "espectador" no iria conectada a nada entonces? tengo problemas entendiendo el tema del rombo, por que vimos muy poco de UML con unos escasos ejemplos ... Se que la herencia la hize bien y los simbolos que indican los modificadores tambien (private, public protected), pero si la clase es "espectador" fuese conectada a algo  seria a "entra espectador"? aunque la verdad no se si llevaria el rombo o sencillamente una linea.. gracias por estar orientandome tengo que dar parcial y de repente me dicen "hey que UML tambien entra"

Comment: El rombo es una agregación. basicamente se puede resumir como que una clase consta de la otra. Por ejemplo un PC consta de teclado, raton, etc. Cuando tienes agregación el rombo se conecta al cuadrado no a sus partes internas.

Comment: Entonces el rombo apunta solo al cuadrado, en una forma de decir "hey el cine consta de x espectador", En uno de los pocos ejemplos que nos dieron habia en una clase principal llamada digamos "inventario " en su  segundo marco un arreglo de la clase "cosas" de ahi salia un rombo que apuntaba hacia el cuadrado donde estaba definida la clase "cosas" donde estaban sus atributos, metodos etc.

Comment: Si algo mas o menos asi.

Comment: No amigo tienes errores de sintaxis , pues estas utilizando variables donde se establecen atributos, estas estas usando métodos donde se establece el valor de la variable